# automatically set permissions for new file

Tags: permissions

I am running Ubuntu 12.04LTS and have a problem with newly downloaded files from torrents. I have tried both qBittorrent and Deluge and the result is the same.

The folders created are 775 and the files are 664. I repeat that this only happens to files downloaded by torrent programs. Any other folder and file created are 777.

I am sharing these files through Samba and I would like them to be 777.

Is there a way for this to happen automatically everytime a file is created?

Answer (score 0):

> [...] I am sharing these files through Samba [...]

There you go :)
The permissions are likely to be defined in

```
/etc/samba/smb.conf
```

Please have a look at the settings for

```
create mask = 
directory mask = 
force create mode = 
force directory mode =
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, simply edit the file `/etc/adduser.conf` and modify the DIR MODE variable to 777 as you want so that all new folders will be created with the new permissions.